# How do you add validation to django rest framework api

Tags: python, django, api, validation, django-rest-framework

I have two models, which look like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Warehouse(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and they have two serializers which look like this:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'sku', 'description', 'price', 'location', 'serial_number')
        #we need a validator that checks if location is in the list of warehouses
        #we need a validator that checks if sku is in the list of products
    

class WarehouseSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Warehouse
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

I need a way to ensure that the location field for newly created items matches an existing name field from a warehouse. I also need the deletion of a warehouse to trigger the deletion of all items in that warehouse, or, failing that; if the warehouse has items, it cannot be deleted.

I'm brand new to python and django, so any help would be massively appreciated!

for reference, my views class looks like

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

class WarehouseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Warehouse.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = WarehouseSerializer
```

if that helps, but from what I can see I don't expect it to.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is your data models. It's clear that a warehouse and an item have a one to many relationship. With that, you would have something like this in your models.

```
from django.db import models


class Warehouse(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, related_name="items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The `on_delete=models.CASCADE` will ensure that all items related to a warehouse are deleted when a warehouse is deleted. The foreign key relationship will ensure that warehouse `id` you provide when creating the item, exists before the item is created.

The other files will look as follows.

#### serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Warehouse, Item


class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'sku', 'description', 'price', 'location', 'serial_number', "warehouse")


class WarehouseSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Warehouse
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'items')
```

#### views.py

```
from .models import Item, Warehouse
from .serializers import ItemSerializer, WarehouseSerializer

from rest_framework import viewsets


class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer


class WarehouseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Warehouse.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = WarehouseSerializer
```